# Trapped in login-loop

Tags: 16.04

I fell victim to the often reported login loop. Simply put, I cannot log onto the desktop of any of the accounts on my Ubuntu 16.04 operating system. I logged in via tty to extract the xsession-error logs, but I sadly can't make heads or tails of those errors.

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  30
  Current serial number in output stream:  31
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gpg-agent pre-start process (1997) terminated with status 1
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2117) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2110) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: logrotate main process (1979) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/linux-headers-4.4.0-96.0.crash) main process (2031) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (2108) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (2151) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (2152) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (2154) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2126) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-keyboard main process (2159) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-printers main process (2175) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (2176) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2043) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity7 pre-start process (2112) terminated with status 143
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I'm pretty sure that my nvidia drivers are the culprit, so if anyone has a quick guide at hand how I can locate and update the drivers, I'm eager to hear it. I'm using the GeForce GT 420.

Comment: Are you sure your running 16.04? Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/900389/upstart-to-systemd

Comment: Yes, I am using the Ubuntu 16.04 LTR version, but I don't see how the thread you linked could help me with my problem.

Comment: 16.04 moved to systemd you appear to have a plethora of upstart jobs running which would lead me to believe you are running 14.04

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but those actually don't seem to be the reason why I can't get on to my dektop, I will check your link out though, thanks for that. Edit: But it seems just as all those errors disappeared after reinstalling the nvidia driver.

Comment: If you are actually running 16.04 `lsb_release -a` to check. You might want this answer on the more popular https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop Your question appears to be a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 0):

[Following this tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/) up to step 4 and reinstalling the nivida driver fixed my problem.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/650253/225694